# How to fix 'String index out of range: 0' when configuring oracle data source in IntellijIdea?

Tags: oracle, intellij-idea

When I set up new oracle data source in IntellijIdea I specify Host, Sid, User, Password in the `General` tab. Resulting url is correct, but when I'm trying to test connection it gives this error *String index out of range: 0*. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it fails is that oracle driver it trying to parse **database property**, which can be set in `Advanced` tab. It should be in the form
`<SERVER>:<PORT>:<SID>`. That should work.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @JWoodchuck Nope

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @JWoodchuck It was quite a while ago, so I've lost the context of this problem.

Comment: No problem. Just kiddin.